# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError при импорте

Tags: python, импорт, модули

У меня есть проект вот с такой структурой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда я пытаюсь в файл file_B импортировать функцию из file_A:

```
from app_1.file_A import function
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_1'
```

В чем заключается проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте `from .app_1 import function`

Comment: @biflé получаю ту же самую ошибку - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_1'"

Comment: Кто вам сказал что таким образом пайтон может делать импорт?

Comment: Пайтон нечего не знает об app_1 в данном случае.

Comment: @Александр, а каким образом можно сделать тогда?